# How to set .runsettings in JetBrains Rider and MSTest

Tags: mstest, jetbrains-ide, rider

How can I set .runsettings for MsTest in JetBrains Rider?

I tried `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Unit Testing | MSTest` and choose the .runsettings file in Test Settings but this has no effect.

Comment: What is your Rider version? Did you try to open your test project in Visual Studio? Please check if your .DotSettings file contains the following: `<s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/Environment/UnitTesting/MsTestProvider/UseTestRunConfigFromMetadataFile/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>`. If it does, change it to false. Or you can do it via VisualStudio: go to "ReSharper | Options | Tools | Unit Testing | Test Frameworks | MsTest -> Test Settings" and switch it to "Use specific test setting file" instead of "Use .runconfig/.testsettings selected in VS UI", then save settings.

Comment: I use Rider 2019.1.2. And yes after I change the property to false in "C:\Users\%USER_HOME%\.Rider2019.1\config\resharper-host\GlobalSettingsStorage.DotSettings" it works fine.

Answer (score 7):

The location may have changed since the original question, but I've found it here:

`JetBrains Rider` > `Preferences...` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Unit Testing` > `MSTest`

You may have a checkbox `Enable MSTest support` which you can check (although seems to be removed in latest Rider version) and there's also a path to your test settings file in the `Test Settings` box.

[image]

Comment: There is not such a choice in Rider. Neither in VS with Resharper Extension.

Comment: The menu item is still there for me (Rider 2020.3.2) and the test settings area is still there for me but the checkbox is no longer there. I've added a picture to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it now :)